# How to search for a repeated unit in a long string using C#

Tags: c#

How to search for a repeated unit in a long string?

```
string foo = "atccuahhqtccuahh";
```

With a repeated substring of `ccuahh`, how can I determine the position where the repeat happen using regex?

---

Thank you guys. But the code posted is not working. I am search for any type of repeat in a string. Anyone can post a tested code to help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know what is a repeated substring?

Comment: Are there any further restrictions or requirements on what constituents a repeated unit? E.g. Do you only want the longest possible repeated string? Do you want all the repeated strings longer than a minimum length? In your example would you also want "tccuahh"? Can the repeated strings be adjacent to each other or are they separated by other characters?

Answer (score 1):

Use the string.IndexOf(string, int) overload.  Start with the *startIndex* argument at 0, you'll get the index of the first match.  Loop, now pass that found index+1 for the argument.

If you want to stick with Regex then use the Match.Index property.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("atccuahhqtccuahh", "ccuahh");
var indices = matches.OfType<Match>().Select((m) => m.Index);
```

Comment: It's useful when OP knows the repeated string

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Regex with grouping.

```
Regex r = new Regex( @"(.+).*\1" );
```

"(.+)" will create a match group for one or more characters and represents the repeated unit. This will need to be adjusted depending on the minimum number of characters you want the repeated unit to have. E.g. replace the '+' in the match group with '{x,}' where x is the minimum number of characters.

The "\1" matches the same characters matched by "(.+)";

Test code:

```
string input = "atccuahhqtccuahh";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(.+).*\1");

foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Index);
    Console.WriteLine(match);

GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' repeated at positions {1} and {2}", 
    groups[0].Value,
    groups[0].Index,
    groups[1].Index);
}
```

Comment: The pattern matching here isn't correct. The \1 is matching exactly the same characters (at the same index) the the group is matching.

Comment: I suspect either a positive or negative lookahead is required to ensure the indexes of the groups differ. E.g. new Regex(@"(([a-z])(?=.*\2))+");

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for actuall reg exp. Here's the one that should work:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(.+).+?\1");
```

However it works a bit weired. In order to match long string (the one that you've used as an example) I had to write it this way:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(.{3,}).+?\1");
```

Without explicit lover boundary spec it matched 'a' and 'hh' only.

Probably I miss something about the way Regex works in .NET ...

Answer (score 0):

What about using LINQ?

```
        string text = "aafffuaffuaffuafffua";
        string search = "fff";

        var byLinq = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length)
                     where text.Length - i - search.Length > 0
                     where text.Substring(i, search.Length) == search
                     select i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use regex? From a quick glimpse it seems you could do this easily with just the normal string methods:

```
int GetIndexOfFirstRepetition(string text, string substring){
  var firstOccurrenceIndex = text.IndexOf(substring);

  var indexToSearchAfter = firstOccurrenceIndex + substring.Length;

  return text.IndexOf(substring, indexToSearchAfter);
}
```

I'm assuming that the substring is actually repeated, and that by "find position where the repeat happened" you want the second occurrence of the substring, not the first.